# What does the 'array name' mean in case of array of char pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

In my code:

```
 char *str[] = {"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};
 printf("%d %d", sizeof(str), sizeof(str[0]));
```

I'm getting the output as `12 2`, so my doubts are:

1. Why is there a difference?
2. Both `str` and `str[0]` are char pointers, right?

Comment: No, not right at all. `str` is an array, `str[0]` an array element.

Comment: the output ? or any syntax??

Comment: Are you quite sure of the values 12 and 2 you say you are getting? That would be an unusual architecture. By the way, `%d` is the wrong format to print a `size_t` (the type of `sizeof(…)`). One solution here would be to ensure there is no misunderstanding with `(int)sizeof(str)` and `(int)sizeof(str[0])`.

Comment: @NithishInpursuitOfhappiness Read: [What does sizeof(&arr) returns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-returns/15177499#15177499)

Comment: The output you say you are getting is unrealistic. It can't be 12 and 2.

Comment: On whatever architecture you are, the first value should be 4 times the second one. On a 32 bit machine, you should get `16 4`, on a 64 bit one `32 8`. On a very old one or on an embedded system, you might even get `8 2`, but never `12 2` as the array contains 4 element of the same size

Comment: @glglgl There have been architectures where pointers to different types have different sizes. Though the OP probably is not using one of these.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Even then this wouldn't apply here: the array should have `n` times the size of a `char *`, whatever this is, with `n` being the number of array elements.

Comment: `sizeof(str)=size of str array = (number of element)*sizeof(char*)`
`sizeof(str[0]) = size of first element = sizeof(char*)`

Comment: @Dayalrai Right. As I said.

Comment: @NithishInpursuitOfhappiness  One more good question can be how they stored in memory. Please check [help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17564608/revisions).

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c) too

Comment: @glglgl *`There have been architectures where pointers to different types have different sizes`* **?** reference?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1539196/296974), referring to the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html): "Some 64-bit Cray machines represent `int *` in the lower 48 bits of a word; `char *` additionally uses some of the upper 16 bits to indicate a byte address within a word."

Comment: BTW, your question should address @PascalCuoq, as you quote from him.

Comment: why are 20 people following this question

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I guess this could be a 16 bit architecture, but I can't explain how he got `printf` to emit values in base 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most cases, an array name will decay to the value of the address of its first element, and with type being the same as a pointer to the element type. So, you would expect a bare `str` to have the value equal to `&str[0]` with type pointer to pointer to `char`.

However, this is not the case for `sizeof`. In this case, the array name maintains its type for `sizeof`, which would be array of 4 pointer to `char`.

The return type of `sizeof` is a `size_t`. If you have a C99 compiler, you can use `%zu` in the format string to print the value returned by `sizeof`.

Comment: But that doesn't explain the `12 2`... nevertheless +1

Comment: @glglgl The “12 2” is probably explained by `size_t` being 64-bit and invoking undefined behavior when passed to `printf` with a `%d` format, as per my comment.

Comment: @PascalCuoq This might be the case, but then I'd rather expect a `0` somewhere, no matter if little or big endian... But one never knows what strange things the one or other platform makes.

Comment: If your implementation supports it, use `"%zu"` to print a `size_t` value. If it doesn't (Microsoft likely doesn't), use `"%lu"` and convert the value to `unsigned long`. Or, if you're lazy and the values are known to be small, use `"%d"` and convert to `int`.

Comment: The unconventional values may also be the result of not including a proper prototype for `printf` in the program, and so the system applied the variable argument macros to something random.

Answer (score 66):

<sub>Through the question is already answered and accepted, but I am adding some more description (also answering the original question) that I guess will be helpful for new users. (as I searched,  this description is not explained anywhere else (at-least on stackoverflow) hence I am adding now.</sub>

First read:  [`sizeof` Operator](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html)

> **6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator, 1125:**
>   When you apply the `sizeof` operator to an array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.

According to this when  `sizeof` is applied to the name of a static array identifier (*not* allocated through malloc), the result is the size in bytes of the whole array rather then just address. This is one of the [few exceptions to the rule that the name of an array is converted/decay to a pointer to the first element of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer/17753057#17753057), and it is possible just because the actual array size is fixed and known at compile time, when `sizeof` operator evaluates.

To understand it better consider the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 char a1[6],       // One dimensional
     a2[7][6],     // Two dimensional 
     a3[5][7][6];  // Three dimensional

 printf(" sizeof(a1)   : %lu \n", sizeof(a1));
 printf(" sizeof(a2)   : %lu \n", sizeof(a2));
 printf(" sizeof(a3)   : %lu \n", sizeof(a3));
 printf(" Char         : %lu \n", sizeof(char));
 printf(" Char[6]      : %lu \n", sizeof(char[6]));
 printf(" Char[5][7]   : %lu \n", sizeof(char[7][6]));
 printf(" Char[5][7][6]: %lu \n", sizeof(char[5][7][6]));

 return 1;
}
```

Its output:

```
 sizeof(a1)   : 6 
 sizeof(a2)   : 42 
 sizeof(a3)   : 210 
 Char         : 1 
 Char[5]      : 6 
 Char[5][7]   : 42 
 Char[5][7][6]: 210
```

Check above working at @[codepad](http://codepad.org/LZx8iIkl), notice size of `char` is one byte, it you replace `char` with `int` in above program then every output will be multiplied by `sizeof(int)` on your machine.

### Difference between `char* str[]` and `char str[][]` and how both are stored in memory

**Declaration-1:** `char *str[] = {"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};`

In this declaration `str[]` is an *array of pointers* to char. Every index `str[i]` points to first char of strings in `{"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};`.
Logically `str`  should be arranged in memory in following way:

```
Array Variable:                Constant Strings:
---------------                -----------------

         str:                       201   202   203   204  205   206
        +--------+                +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
 343    |        |= *(str + 0)    | 'f' | 'o' | 'r' | 'g' | 's' | '\0'|
        | str[0] |-------|        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
        | 201    |       +-----------▲
        +--------+                  502   503  504
        |        |                +-----+-----+-----+
 347    | str[1] |= *(str + 1)    | 'd' | 'o' | '\0'|
        | 502    |-------|        +-----+-----+-----+
        +--------+       +-----------▲
        |        |                  43    44    45    46
 351    | 43     |                +-----+-----+-----+-----+
        | str[2] |= *(str + 2)    | 'n' | 'o' | 't' | '\0'|
        |        |-------|        +-----+-----+-----+-----+
        +--------+       +-----------▲
 355    |        |
        | 9002   |                 9002  9003   9004 9005
        | str[3] |                +-----+-----+-----+-----+
        |        |= *(str + 3)    | 'd' | 'i' | 'e' | '\0'|
        +--------+       |        +-----+-----+-----+-----+
                         +-----------▲


Diagram: shows that str[i] Points to first char of each constant string literal. 
Memory address values are assumption.
```

Note: `str[]` is stored in continue memory allocations and every string is stored in memory at random address (not in continue space).

**[ANSWER]**

According to [Codepad](http://codepad.org/x81eNQaY) following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *str[] = {"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};
    printf("sizeof(str): %lu,  sizeof(str[0]): %lu\n", 
            sizeof(str), 
            sizeof(str[0])
    );  
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(str): 16,  sizeof(str[0]): 4
```

- In this code `str` is an array for *4* char-addresses, where each `char*` is size 4 bytes, so according to above quote total size of array is `4 * sizeof(char*)` = 16 bytes.
- Datatype of `str`  is `char*[4]`.
- `str[0]` is nothing but pointer to char, so its four bytes. Datetype of `str[i]` is `char*`.

<sub>(note: in some system address can be 2-byte or 8-bytes)</sub>

Regarding output one should also read [glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-variable-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers#comment25553764_17564608) to the question:

> On whatever architecture you are, the first value should be 4 times the second one. 
>   On a 32 bit machine, you should get 16 4, on a 64 bit one 32 8. On a very old one 
>   or on an embedded system, you might even get 8 2, but never 12 2 as the array contains 4 element of the same size

Additional points:

- Because each `str[i]`  points to a  `char*` (and string) is variable, `str[i]` can be assigned a new string's address for example: `str[i] = "yournewname";` is valid for `i = 0 to < 4`.

One more important point to notice:

- In our above example `str[i]` pointing to constant string literal that can't be modified; hence `str[i][j] = 'A'` is invalid (we can't write on read only memory) and doing this will be a runtime error.
  But suppose if `str[i]` points to a simple char array then `str[i][j] = 'A'` can be a valid expression.
  Consider following code:

  ```
    char a[] = "Hello"; // a[] is simple array
    char *str[] = {"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};
    //str[0][4] = 'A'; // is error because writing on read only memory
    str[0] = a;
    str[0][5] = 'A'; // is perfectly valid because str[0] 
                     // points to an array (that is not constant)
  ```

Check here working code: [Codepad](http://codepad.org/gpgBO0Fs)

**Declaration-2:**  `char str[][6] = {"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};`:

Here `str` is a two-dimensional array of chars (where each row is equal in size) of size 4 * 6. (remember here you have to give column value in declaration of `str` explicitly, but row is 4 because of number of strings are 4)
In memory `str[][]` will be something like below in diagram:

```
                    str
                    +---201---202---203---204---205---206--+
201                 | +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+|   
str[0] = *(str + 0)--►| 'f' | 'o' | 'r' | 'g' | 's' | '\0'||
207                 | +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+|
str[1] = *(str + 1)--►| 'd' | 'o' | '\0'| '\0'| '\0'| '\0'||
213                 | +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+|
str[2] = *(str + 2)--►| 'n' | 'o' | 't' | '\0'| '\0'| '\0'||
219                 | +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+|
str[3] = *(str + 3)--►| 'd' | 'i' | 'e' | '\0'| '\0'| '\0'||
                    | +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+|
                    +--------------------------------------+
  In Diagram:                                 
  str[i] = *(str + i) = points to a complete i-row of size = 6 chars. 
  str[i] is an array of 6 chars.
```

This arrangement of 2D array in memory is called [Row-Major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Row-major_order):
A multidimensional array in linear memory is organized such that rows are stored one after the other. It is the approach used by the C programming language.

Notice differences in both diagrams.

- In second case, complete two-dimensional char array is allocated in continue memory.
- For any `i = 0 to 2`, `str[i]` and `str[i + 1]` value is different by 6 bytes (that is equals to length of one row).
- Double boundary line in this diagram means `str` represents complete 6 * 4 = 24 chars.

Now consider similar code you posted in your question for 2-dimensional char array, check at [Codepad](http://codepad.org/qfbfy9i6):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char str[][6] = {"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};
    printf("sizeof(str): %lu,  sizeof(str[0]): %lu\n", 
            sizeof(str), 
            sizeof(str[0])
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(str): 24,  sizeof(str[0]): 6
```

According to the `sizeof` operator's treatment with array, On application of 2-d array size of should return the entire array size that is 24 bytes.

- As we know, `sizeof` operator returns the size of the entire array on applying array name. So for `sizeof(str)` it returns = 24 that is size of complete 2D char array consists of 24 chars (6-cols* 4-rows).
- In this declaration type  of `str` is `char[4][6]`.
- One more interesting point is `str[i]` represents an array chats and it's type is `char[6]`. And `sizeof(str[0])` is complete array's size = 6 (row length).

Additional points:

- In second declaration `str[i][j]` is not constant, and its content can be changes e.g. `str[i][j] = 'A'` is a valid operation.
- `str[i]` is name of char array of type `char[6]` is a constant and assignment to `str[i]` e.g. `str[i] = "newstring"` is illegal operation (infect it will be compilation-time error).

One more important difference between two declarations:

In **Declaration-1**: `char *str[] = {"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};`, type of `&str` is `char*(*)[4]`, its address of array of char pointers.

In **Declaration-2**: `char str[][6] = {"forgs", "do", "not", "die"};`, type of `&str` is `char(*)[4][6]`,  its address of 2-D char array of 4 rows and 6 cols.

If one wants to read similar description for 1-D array: [What does `sizeof(&array)` return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarr-return/15177499#15177499)

Comment: *... the result is the size of the entire array rather than the size of the pointer represented by the array identifier.* If the identifier represents an array then it doesn't represent any pointer.

Comment: Your quote says "...rather the size of pointer represented by array". An array name doesn't represent a pointer. It can conveniently decay into a pointer but that doesn't make it a pointer.

Comment: You don't really need to quote and explain it yourself. If you want to quote one then look at 6.5.3.4 in C11 which states `...When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array` and may be the definition of sizeof in the same section as well.

Comment: A typo here. The addresses would be (decimal values) `343, 351, 359, 367` instead of `343, 344, 345, 346`. for 32-bit architecture

Comment: @noufal Thanks corrected the typo you noticed, but I am assuming 4 byte `char*` according to codepade I linked the code

Answer (score 6):

It's `16 4` on my computer, and I can explain this: `str` is an array of `char*`, so   `sizeof(str)==sizeof(char*)*4`

I don't know why you get `12 2` though.

Answer (score 3):

The two pointers are different. `str` is an `array of char pointers`, in your example is a (`char*[4]`), and the `str[0]` is a `char pointer`.

The first `sizeof` returns the size of the four char pointers that contains, and the second returns the sizeof of the `char*`.
In my tests the results are:

```
sizeof(str[0]) = 4   // = sizeof(char*)

sizeof(str) = 16  
            = sizeof(str[0]) + sizeof(str[1]) + sizeof(str[2]) + sizeof(str[3])
            = 4 * sizeof(char*)  
            = 4 * 4
            = 16
```