# Storing strings in a char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-strings

I have an array `uint8_t arr[512]` and I need to store a string, IP address and a 32digit number in this array. So I thought of defining another array of strings as below.

```
uint8_t *ch[] = {
     "abcd",
     "1.1.1.1",
     "123456782341223344445"
};
```

Then do a `memcpy` into the `arr[512]`. Is this OK? I think I may not be able to retrieve the IP address from the `arr`. Any other ideas please. Thanks for your time.

Comment: **No** , look [Difference between `char* str[]` and char `str[][]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-array-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers/17661444#17661444) to know how `*ch[]` stored in memory, memcopy need `source` in continues memory whereas its **not**.

Comment: Unrelated: why `uint8_t*` instead of `char*`?

Comment: Why not a `struct` that contains a string, a 32Bit-Integer for the IP-adress and a second string for the 32-digit number?

Comment: @MyPasswordIsLasercats do you mean a `struct` instead of `arr[512]` or `ch[]` ? can you please elaborate.

Comment: @foo_l, can *you* elaborate? It's not at all clear what you begin with and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @StoryTeller OK!.. I just want to store strings and others into the arr[512]. So when I try to retrieve them `a[0]` must be `a` `a[1] = b a[2] = c a[3]=1 a[4]=1 a[5]=1 a[6]=1 a[7]=1`and so on.. Am I clear now?

Comment: @foo_l check Dmitriy Katkov's solution

Answer (score 4):

If you think about how an array of pointers is stored in memory, you would understand why it can't be done.

Your string array looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| ch[0] | ch[1] | ch[2] |
+-------+-------+-------+
   |       |       |
   |       |       v
   |       |       "abcd"
   |       v
   |       "1.1.1.1"
   v
   "123456782341223344445"
```

So if you do a `memcpy` from the `ch` array you only copy the *pointers*, not the actual strings.

---

You can of course copy each string in the array separately into the destination array, but then it's no different than doing it to separate and unrelated strings.

Comment: Agreed. But how can I store the strings and others in `arr[512]`?

Comment: @foo_l Copy them one by one into the destination array, keeping track of where the next string should begin (`strcpy` and `strlen` are good here).

Comment: @foo_l To copy you can also use: `sprintf(arr, "%s %s %s", ch[0], ch[1], ch[2]);` in single step. (Yes but Joachim Pileborg's suggestion  is more better *if you don't know number of strings* ("ip") you wish to copy from `ch[]` and *you will need a loop*)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `snprintf` is a better choice, to not risk buffer overflows.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, I forgot to share a [tool](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw) with you, your answer says you will like it!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's a good idea. Better use structures.

```
struct info
{
  char* name;
  char* address;
  char* number; // or other type
}
```

You can use `pragma pack` if you want to copy full struct to the array. Or use something like copy to combine them.

And if you want to copy it to static array you need to check name length.

Comment: suggestion: use a 32Bit-Integer for the adress

Answer (score 0):

You can do so if you `memcpy()` the strings `ch[0]` to `ch[2]` including ithe terminating `\0`. You can't just `memcpy()` the complete array `ch`. To retrieve the second string from within `arr` you can use `strlen()` or `memchr()`:

```
char *ip = arr + strlen(arr) + 1;
```

or

```
char *ip = memchr( arr, '\0', sizeof( arr ) ) + 1;
```

Personally I would prefere the first option, as it is easier to adpopt to get the third string.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that `uint8_t arr[512]` is not the same kind of type as `uint8_t *ch[]`.
The first one is an array of 512 bytes.
The second is an array of pointers to bytes.
You may have serious problems. So please hep us and tell us what you really want to do.

Comment: I just want to store strings and others into the `arr[512]`. So when I try to retrieve them `a[0]` must be `a` `a[1] = b` `a[2] = c` `a[3]=1` `a[4]=1` `a[5]=1` `a[6]=1` `a[7]=1` and so on...