# c++ pointers:-why is this code not running

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char a[2][5]={"hell","worl"};

char **p;
p=a;  // error here
cout<<*(*(a+1)+1);
cout<<endl;
cout<<(*a)[2];
return 0;
}
```

error:

```
C:\Dev-Cpp\main.cpp [Error] initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. You can't assign a 2D array to a double pointer.

Comment: TIL that I forgot that you can't do that, and now I feel bad for being  confused as to why this wasn't working. haha

Comment: but same kind of code works with 1-D array. int main(int argc, char** argv) { int a[2]={1,2}; int *p; p=a; cout<<*p; return 0; }

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code. Please double check your question.

Comment: @user2819483 An `int *p` is a pointer to an int. A `char **p` is a pointer to a pointer to a character. It is not a pointer to a 2D character array.

Comment: @chris Don't lie arrays are pointers. And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953681/why-pointer-to-pointer-is-a-matrix/17953693#17953693) answer explain why pointer is array and double pointer is matrix. But the part about assignment is correct. So don't lie :)

Comment: @ST3 Arrays are _not_ pointers, and never have been in C or C++.  Anything which says the contrary is wrong.  (And the answer you cite glosses over quite a few details.  In particular, the fact that the `[]` isn't defined on an array type, so that implicit conversions enter into play.)

Comment: @ST3, [Please provide an example where they *are* the same.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c90032019ea00ab)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect it to work?  You declare `p` as `char**`,
and you try to assign a `char[2][5]` to it.  The `char[2][5]`
will convert implicitly to a `char (*)[5]`, but afterwards, you
have a pointer, and no further implicit conversions.  (EDIT: except to `void*`.)

If you think about it, it should be obvious.  If you dereference
a `char**`, you get a `char*`.  And this `char*` must reside
somewhere in memory, since you have a pointer to it.  So where
is it?

If you want to iterate over the outer array in your example:

```
char (*p)[5] = a;
std::cout << *p[0] << sdt::endl;
std::cout << *p[1] << sdt::endl;
```

Note that your expression `*(*(a+1)+1)` also supposes that you
have an array of pointers somewhere.

Or you can use the usual solution when working with C style
strings:

```
char const* const a[] = { "hell", "worl" };
```

and

```
char const* const* p = a;
```

In this case, you do have an array of pointers, which does
implicitly convert to a pointer to a pointer (the first element
of the array).

(Of course, the only time you'll really want to use C style
strings is with const variables with static lifetimes.  In
most other cases, `std::string` is preferable.)

Answer (score -1):

Other way to access the a[2][5] is,

```
  char **p=(char**)a;
```

to get a[0]

```
 printf("\n a[0] is [%s]", ((char*)p));
```

to get a[1]

```
 printf("\n a[1] is [%s]", (((char*)p) + strlen(a[0])+1));
```

hope this helps.