# Difference between pointer to pointer and pointer to 2d array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-to-pointer

1. If I have a 2d array B defined as :

   ```
   int B[2][3] = {{1,3,5},{2,4,6}};
   ```

   Is `int **p = B` same as `int (*p)[3] = B` ?
2. `int **f = B;  printf("%d ",*f+1);`

   gives `5` as output while `printf("%d ",*f)` gives 1 as answer. Why
   is that happening?
3. `printf("%d ",**f);`

   returns a segmentation fault! Why?

Comment: yeah! its a typo. Corrected it

Comment: That's a pointer to a 1D array, not a pointer to a 2D array.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17953693/1237747) may be a bit helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. `int **p = B;` is an error. (Both a compilation error, and a logical error). An `int **` must point to an `int *`. However, there are no `int *` stored in `B`. `B` is a group of contiguous `int`s with no pointers involved.
2. `int **f = B;` must give a compilation error. The behaviour of any executable generated as a result is completely undefined.
3. See 2.

---

To explain why you might be seeing `1` and `5`. (The C standard does not define this, but your compiler bulls on ahead anyway).  Probably your compiler treats the line as

```
int **f = (int **)B;
```

Then the expression `*f` will read bytes from the storage of `B` (which actually hold `int`s) and pretend that those are the bytes that make up a pointer representation. This is further undefined behaviour (violation of strict-aliasing rules). Probably the result of this is that `*f` is a pointer to address `0x00000001`.

Then you print a pointer by using `%d`, causing further undefined behaviour. You see `1` because your system uses the same method for passing `int` to `printf` as it does to pass `int *`.

When you add 1 to `(int *)0x00000001`, you get `(int *)0x00000005`, because incrementing a pointer means to point to the next element of that type.

When you dereference this pointer, it causes a segfault because that address is outside of your valid address space.

Comment: on C99 it just gives a warning
`warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`

Comment: @Dubby the technical term is *a diagnostic*, and the program is ill-formed. It's up to the individual compiler if it wants to proceed after that (and the behaviour has left the realm of what is covered by the C standard)

Comment: So basically a declaration like `char *argv[]` is not a 2 dimensional array i.e. not the same as `char argv[m][n]` ?

Comment: @Dubby; Yes. Its not the same. Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: No, that's a function parameter and the meaning of those is different to variable declarations. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

1) Is `int **p = b` same as `int (*p)[3] = b` ? - No. `int **p = b` is an error.

Because here `int **p` is a pointer to pointer to an integer, but `int (*p)[3]` is pointer to an array of 3 integers!

2) `int **f = B;` It is an error, May results in Undefined behavior!

3) `printf("%d ",**f);` - It is same as (2). `int **f = B;` is error, so Undefined behavior!

NOTE: To avoid this type of error enable some warning flags in compiler option and try!