# chararray size and length are not the same

Tags: c, arrays

I just started learning C after I already got a few years experience in Python, C# and Java.

I learned in a tutorial, that `char anything[]` is always a pointer. (Today, someone told me this is wrong) - I think my question has something to do with this.
Nevertheless, I'm trying to get the length of a char-array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_string_length(char * string)
{
    int length = 0;
    while(string[length] != '\0')
    {   
        char c = string[length];
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

int get_string_size(char * string)
{
    return sizeof(string);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", get_string_size("hello world")); // returns 8
    printf("%d\n", get_string_length("hello world")); // returns 11
    printf("%d\n", sizeof("hello world")); // returns 12 -> Okay, because of '\0'-char
    return 0;
}
```

result:

> 8
>
> 11
>
> 12

so, why is my `get_string_size`-method  returning 8 instead of 12? (Since both only call `sizeof()`)

Comment: `get_string_size(char*)` returns 8 because that's the size in bytes of a pointer on your machine, you can use `strlen(char*)` to get what I guess is your expected result.

Comment: So many answeres in that short time - and also a duplicate ... I think I'm really at starting point of C... :D  thanks for all answeres... I think I need to read a bit more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char anything[]` is a pointer? Not quite.

The actual type of the *literal* `"hello world"` is a `const char[12]`. (Note the extra element for the NUL-terminator).

But when passed to a function, this type *decays* to a `const char*`.

So `get_string_size` returns `sizeof(const char*)` which is 8 on your platform (i.e. the sizeof a `char*`), but `sizeof("hello world")` is `sizeof(const char[12])` which is 12, since `sizeof (char)` is defined by the C standard to be 1.

`get_string_length` is returning the position of the first NUL terminator starting from the pointer passed to it.

Finally, note that you should use `%zu` as the format specifier for the `sizeof` return type: technically the behaviour of `printf("%d\n", sizeof("hello world"));` is *undefined*.

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof("test"));` actually prints `zu` with my code...

Answer (score 2):

Always use *strlen()* to determine the length of a string.

Using *sizeof()* for string length is dangerous and should be avoided. *sizeof()* returns the size of the given type, and this case the given type is a pointer (your system must be 64-bit since the size is 8).

Consider this code and its output:

```
char string[] = "This is a test";
char *pointer = string;

printf("sizeof string: %zu\n", sizeof(string));
printf("sizeof pointer: %zu\n", sizeof(pointer));
printf("strlen pointer: %zu\n", strlen(pointer));

sizeof string: 15
sizeof pointer: 8
strlen pointer: 14
```

Comment: yeah I know about `strlen()` - it's just for learning :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger understood. Use sizeof() only when determining the length of a character array (not pointer). See my above example.

Comment: this actually prints 3 times "zu" as values :D problem with my compiler??

Comment: @MatthiasBurger try %u or %lu instead

Comment: @MatthiasBurger curious what compiler are you using?

Comment: With `%u` or `%lu` it works. I'm using the Visual Studio x64 Command-Prompt for now (So commandline-compiler? It's compiled with e.g. `cl myfile.c`). Should I switch? If yes, what compiler would you suggest? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135073/discussion-between-henry-rillovian-and-matthias-burger).

Answer (score 1):

This does not do what you think:

```
int get_string_size(char * string)
{
    return sizeof(string);
}
```

Here `sizeof(string)` is the size of the pointer, which is always 8 on your (presumably 64-bit) platform. On a 32-bit platform it would be most likely 4 instead of 8.

On the other hand `sizeof("hello world")` is the memory size taken by the string literal `"hello world"`, which is 11 + 1 (+1 for the NUL terminator).