# Is a matrix int mat[5][5] the same thing as an int **?

Tags: c

Simple 1-dimension arrays are considered as a pointer, but is it also the case for a matrix ?

However, a cube `int[5][5][5]` would also be considered as an `int ***` ?

Comment: Simple 1-dimension arrays are **not** considered a pointer, to begin with. An array's name decays to a pointer when used in certain expressions, but that is quite a different thing.

Comment: You may take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17953693/1237747). Not the right answer, but helpful anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, a pointer to a pointer to an integer is not the same as an array of arrays of integers.

Think about how they would look in memory.

Array of arrays (e.g. `int a[2][2]`):

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Pointer to pointer (e.g. `int **a`):

```
+------+------+------+
| a[0] | a[1] | .... |
+------+------+------+
   |      |
   |      v
   |      +---------+---------+---------+
   |      | A[1][0] | a[1][1] | ....... |
   |      +---------+---------+---------+
   v
   +---------+---------+---------+
   | A[0][0] | a[0][1] | ....... |
   +---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

No they are not. For example consider the two declarations given below.

```
int c[5][5][5];
int ***d;
```

For the first declaration the memory requirement is 125 X 4 = 500 Bytes.

Where as for the second declaration the memory requirement is just 4 Bytes. For many practical purposes we can interchange between an array and a pointer but they are not the same.

Comment: I think this somewhat misses the more important point, which is that you cannot do `d = c`.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously Not. An array of array of integers are different from pointer to pointer to integer.
Array is a collection of similar data elements stored in contiguous memory location. But pointer to pointer to integers are not.

```
int a[5][5];
```

In this declaration, it will allocate contiguous memory location for all elements. say starting memory location is 1000.

```
array  starting   array elements
       address
a[0]--> 1000 --> a[0][0] a[0][1] ... a[0][4]
a[1]--> 1020 --> a[1][0] a[1][1] ... a[1][4]
a[2]--> 1040 --> a[2][0] a[2][1] ... a[2][4]
a[3]--> 1060 --> a[3][0] a[3][1] ... a[3][4]
a[4]--> 1080 --> a[4][0] a[4][1] ... a[4][4]
```

But when you have pointer to pointer to integer like this-

```
int **a;
```

when you allocate memory for this-

```
array --> a[0] a[1] a[2] a[3] a[4]  
address > 1000 1004 1008 1012 1016 // address of array which points to some other location
```

This will be allocated contiguous memory locations. but each array will point/ holds some other memory location for elements.

```
array's  array  element's   array elements
address         address
1000 --> a[0]--> 2000 --> a[0][0] a[0][1] ... a[0][4]
1004 --> a[1]--> 3000 --> a[1][0] a[1][1] ... a[1][4]
1008 --> a[2]--> 4000 --> a[2][0] a[2][1] ... a[2][4]
1012 --> a[3]--> 5000 --> a[3][0] a[3][1] ... a[3][4]
1016 --> a[4]--> 6000 --> a[4][0] a[4][1] ... a[4][4]
```

These arrays holds the starting address of their elements in different locations.