# Different pointer notations in 2D Arrays?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

These are the notations used for 2D Arrays

```
char (*names)[5] ;
```

and

```
char* names[] = {"Jan","Feb"};
```

and

```
char names[3][5] = { Initializers..};
```

I'm getting extremely confused between these notations.

The 1st one declares names to be a pointer to an array of 5 chars i.e

```
names -> a char pointer -> "Some string"
```

The 3rd one has a different memory map, i.e it is stored in row major order like a normal array unlike the one stated above.

How is the 2nd notation similar or different from the 1st and 3rd notation.?

Also passing them to functions is a different story altogether. If we declare the 2d array to be of type 2, then it is passed as a double pointer (`char** names`) while if it is of type 1 or type 3, the columns should be mentioned in the declaration.

Please help me attain more clarity over these issues.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: Read: [Difference between `char* str[]` and `char str[][]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-array-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers/17661444#17661444) I explained with diagrams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one of those examples is a 2D array:

```
char names[3][5];
```

The others are different:

```
char (*names)[5] ;
```

is a pointer to a 1D array, and:

```
char* names[] = {"Jan","Feb"};
```

is a 1D array of pointers.

I'm going to rename them now to be clearer:

```
char a[3][5];
char (*b)[5];
char *c[3];
```

`a` is the only real two dimensional array.  That is, it occupies contiguous memory and has room for three strings, each 5 characters long (including null terminator).

`b` is a pointer to an array; no storage for any potential contents of that array is included.

`c` is an array of pointers, each can be used to point to any string you happen to care about; no storage is reserved for any of the strings themselves, just for the three pointers.

If you have a function with a prototype like:

```
void myfunction(char **p);
```

Only `c` can be passed to this function; the others won't behave the way you'd like them to.

Comment: Additionally, the array of 5 `char` that `b` points to may be an element of an array of arrays of 5 `char`, so it `b` be used access a two-dimensional array. `b = a` is a legal assignment.