# How to skip over rows in multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, pointers

I want to skip p from the start of `{0,1,2,3}`, to `{4,5,6,7}` etc.  How do I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char td[6][4] = { 
                      {0, 1, 2, 3}, 
                      {4, 5, 6, 7}, 
                      {8, 9, 10, 11}, 
                      {12, 13, 14, 15}, 
                      {16, 17, 18, 19}, 
                      {20, 21, 22, 23}  
                    };
    char* p = *td;  

    printf("Address of td: \t%p, value=%u\n", td, (int)**td);
    printf("Address of p: \t%p, value=%u\n", p, (int)*p);
    p++;   
    /* How do I skip to the start of {4,5,6,7} (ie to be pointing at 4) ? */ 
    printf("Address of p: \t%p, value=%u\n", p, (int)*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *`How do I skip to the start of {4,5,6,7} (ie to be pointing at 4) ?`*  Which is next `4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first read [this answer: `Declaration-2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-array-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers/17661444#17661444): Where I explained how char 2-D array stored in memory.

`char*` `p` points to `td[0][0]` element in array that is `0`. If you wants to increment `p` such that `p` point to `4` that is `td[1][0]` then increment `p` by number of cols = 4 (array is row = 6 * col = 4).

```
p = p + 4;
```

Check [this working](http://codepad.org/yImC06H0) code. I applied concept of [row-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Row-major_order).

Answer (score 0):

In order to skip to the next row, you need a pointer which points to the row containing four elements not a pointer to a single element.

So, the pointer would look like `char (*p)[4] = td` now when you increment p by one it will be pointing to the next row ({4,5,6,7})

Also, your initialization of the character pointer is incorrect, it should be `char *p = td`

Comment: No his `p` is `char*`

Answer (score 0):

td + 1 will also skip by 4 elements.
Because td is pointing to first array consist of 4 elements.It is a pointer to a array

```
printf("Address of p: \t%p, value=%u\n", *(td+1), **(td+1));
```

example

```
char a[row][col];

for(i = 0 ; i < row*col ; i++)
  printf("%c", *(*a+i) );
```

this will print the whole 2d array with just one loop.