# How to do casting in NASM similar to the way it's done in C?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Say, I've defined a struct already in Assembly.  How can I do this?

```
    struct some_struct_t *s1 = (struct some_struct_t *)some_buffer;
```

where

```
char some_buffer[1024];
malloc = malloc(1024);
memset(some_buffer, 0, 1024);
```

I can think of lea or mov, but how exactly?

Comment: asm doesn't care about types, it's your job to use the proper instructions appropriate for your type. In case of structs that also includes using the correct offsets to the members.

Comment: @Jester, can you show me an example?

Comment: An example for accessing a struct member? `mov eax, [edx+8]` if you have your pointer already in `edx` and you want to load a member of size 4 starting at offset 8.

Comment: @Jester, no, the example I'll use to get an answer for  my question

Comment: He just did.  Why don't you take some C code with a structure, compile it to assembly and have a look at it.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, no, he didn't.

Comment: You're failure to understand doesn't mean that you weren't provided with an accurate answer. assembly doesn't type data and accessing structure elements, which is an artificial high level construct, is accomplished by offsetting from the start of the construct by the size of the intervening elements.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this C code (with implementation-defined behaviour)

```
void foo()
{
    struct struct1* s1 = (struct struct1*)0x01234567;  /* exp1 */
    struct struct2* s2 = (struct struct2*)0x01234567;  /* exp2 */
    struct struct3* s3 = (struct struct3*)0x01234567;  /* exp3 */
    float* f = (float*)0x01234567;                     /* exp4 */
    int* i = (int*)0x01234567;                         /* exp5 */
    char* c = (char*)0x01234567;                       /* exp6 */
}
```

Assuming `s1` is at `[rsp-08h]` for the sake of clarity, then *exp1* is assembled as

```
mov QWORD [rsp-08h], 1234567h
```

Assuming `s2` is at `[rsp-10h]` for the sake of clarity, then *exp2* is assembled as

```
mov QWORD [rsp-10h], 1234567h
```

Assuming `s3` is at `[rsp-18h]` for the sake of clarity, then *exp3* is assembled as

```
mov QWORD [rsp-18h], 1234567h
```

Assuming `f` is at `[rsp-20h]` for the sake of clarity, then *exp4* is assembled as

```
mov QWORD [rsp-20h], 1234567h
```

Assuming `i` is at `[rsp-28h]` for the sake of clarity, then *exp4* is assembled as

... [haven't you got it yet?](https://godbolt.org/g/OAgAE0)

---

There is no such thing as a type in assembly and consequently no such thing as a cast.
There is only data in assembly, that's why we invented typed high-level languages, not for the `if`s nor for the `for`s but for the *type checking*.

If you want to do `struct some_struct_t *s1 = (struct some_struct_t *)some_buffer;` then that translates as `s1 = some_buffer`.
That's just an assignment of values.

---

Now since `some_buffer` is an array with automatic storage, and this translates as "it is on the stack" on x86, you may wonder what exactly is the semantic of `struct some_struct_t *s1 = (struct some_struct_t *)some_buffer;` *besides the (artificial) cast* that, as you now know, only lives for the duration of the compilation process.

[You surely know that `some_buffer` decay into a pointer to the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518255/why-is-array-name-a-pointer-to-the-first-element-of-the-array), then the only hard thing to do, in translating that instruction, is figuring out the address of the first element.

Well, I can't tell you very much about this because I don't know where you placed the first item but in general `some_buffer` is on the stack so this, once adjusted, will do

```
;Compute the address of the first element
lea rax, [rsp+...]         ;or [rbp-...] if a frame pointer is available

;Store it in a local var
mov QWORD [rsp+...], rax   ;As above, also you can use any other scratch reg
```

Where the first ellipsis is used in place of the offset, relative to `rsp` of the first item of the array.
The second one is used in place of the offset of the `s1` pointer.

For a [live example see here](https://godbolt.org/g/urPtK1).
Note that in that example GCC is being overly zealous in using the Red zone, but we can forgive him as I had to disable *any* optimisation in order to have a sensible disassembly.

---

If you wonder how you can do the same for `malloc` then, if you still don't want to use [godbolt.org](http://godbolt.org), the solution is here

```
mov edi, 1024
call malloc
mov QWORD [rsp+...], rax
```

Comment: thanks. 1) is it qword in `mov QWORD [rsp-08h], 1234567h` and others because it's fo x64 system? for x32 it'll be   `mov DWORD [rsp-08h], 1234567h`? 2) shouldn't `mov QWORD [rsp-08h], 1234567h` be without qword or anything else in nasm?

Comment: You can't use `rsp` in x86 since it's a 64 bit register/.  You use `esp`, which is a 32 bit register.

Comment: Just an added note:  You can disabled the red-zone behavior.

Comment: @Jojika You can omit `QWORD` in this case. I used it just to make memory access more visible, it's just style.