# C string length

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

when I explicitly state the value of a string, then compare it to itself, system returns FALSE. Does this have something to do with the extra '\0' character added by the system? And how should I refine my code to make it TRUE?

```
char name[5] = "hello";

if(name == "hello")
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: In C you can't compare strings like that, what you are doing is comparing two *pointers* that will never be equal. Read about [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) for how to compare strings. Also, remember that strings needs to be *terminated*. A string of five characters needs space for *six* characters to include the terminator. Both of these facts should be in any [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You need `char name[6] = "hello";` to hold `'hello`  (or even better `char name[] = "hello";`) if you intend to use `name` as a *string*. Why? (hint: you forgot `+1`  for the *nul-terminating* character `:)`  If you do not plan to use `name` as a *string`, then know you cannot use any of the `string.h` function that expect a *nul-terminated string* as a parameter.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried `char name1[] = "hello";` then  `char name2[] = "hello";` and finally `strcmp(name1, name2)` but still FALSE. How can something so simple be so frustrating...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11399682/694576

Comment: `(strcmp(name1, name2) == 0)` works. I looked at documentation. Dumb me.

Comment: @reiallenramos, that isn't frustrating, that is correct. If the strings are equal `if (strcmp(name1, name2) == 0)` then the strings are equal `:)`

Comment: Change `char name[5]` to `char name[]` - Get the compiler to compute the right size for you (PS: It is not 5)

Comment: @EdHeal `char name[] = "hello";` works but when change it to `char name[];` only, it gives an error. Why is this?

Comment: `char name[] = "hello";` - Compiler is told to create an array of characters? What is it contents/size - It can find that out from `"Hello"`. `char name[]`. How can the compiler find out the size. It does not know.

Comment: As it stands `name` isn't a C-string, as it is missing the `0`-terminator, as it is defined to be *only* five `char`s long. As it isn't a C-"string", passing it to any member of the `str*()` family of functions invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (usefully) compare strings using `!=` or `==`, you need to use `strcmp` The reason for this is because `!=` and `==` will only compare the base addresses of those strings. Not the contents of the strings.
don't use predefined array size like `char name[5] = "hello";` instead of you can use `char name[] = "hello";` or `char name[6] = "hello";` when use

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char a[] = "hello"; 
char b[] = "hello";

   if (strcmp(a,b) == 0)
      printf("strings are equal.\n");
   else
      printf("strings are not equal.\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from my comment, you need `char name[6] = "hello";` to hold `'hello` (plus the *nul-terminating* character)  Even better, you can use

```
char name[] = "hello";
```

That will properly initialize `name` to contain 6-character (including the *nul-byte*).

All `string.h` functions expect a *nul-terminated string* as a parameter when they take `char *` or `const char *` as parameters passed to the functions.

Lastly, as correctly noted in Anuvansh's answer, you cannot use a inequality condition to determine if two strings equal or differ. You either us the normal comparison functions `strcmp`, `strncmp`, `memcmp` or you walk a pointer down each string stopping at the first char the strings differ on, or on the *nul-byte* if the strings are equivalent.

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions. Gook luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1):

The strcmp() returns 0 if both argument are equal.

```
char name[]="hello";
if(strcmp(name,"hello") == 0)
    return TRUE;
else
    return FALSE;
```

Comment: Passing `name` as defined by the OP to `strcmp()` invokes undefined behaviour, as `name` is *not* `0`-terminated.

Comment: added proper definition for variable "name"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, name is a pointer that points to the address of the string "hello". You can't compare them. So you can try `strcmp` function instead. Also include the `string.h` library.

like:

```
strcmp(name,"hello");
```

also as one of the comment points out, take a char array of 6 to include '`\0`'.

Hope that helps.

Comment: _You can't compare them_ - you can!

Comment: I mean the comparing the address and string is not a meaningful comparison.

Answer (score 0):

In C ,the array name is actually the pointer to the first element of that array.

in your case:

```
if(name == "hello")
```

you compare pointer to the string so it will return false

You can see the same concept in this article
[why is array name a pointer to the first element of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518255/why-is-array-name-a-pointer-to-the-first-element-of-the-array)

You can simply include  "string.h" library and use  strcmp() function

code like this:

```
char name[]="hello";

if(strcmp(name,"hello")==0){

.....

}
```

to make it Ture

Comment: Indent your code by 4-characters to format it as code.

Comment: "*You can simply include library*" In C libraries are not used during compilation, but are *linked after* compilation. What is *included* for compilation is/are the *prototype/s* of the function/s provided by the libraries .