# How does sizeof work with this dereferencing of a pointer to array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here I have a pointer `ptr` to array `arr` of 4 integers. `ptr` points to the whole array. `ptr[0]` or `*ptr` points to the first element of the array, so adding 1 to `ptr[0]` gives the address of the second element of the array.

I can't understand why using `sizeof(ptr[0])` gives the size of the whole array, 16 bytes, not the size of only the first element, 4 bytes, (as `ptr[0]` points to the first element in the array).

```
int arr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int (*ptr)[4] = &arr;
printf("%zd", sizeof(ptr[0])); //output is 16
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be `int *ptr = arr;` ? That would make it point to the start (first element of) the array, which is equivalent to `&arr[0]`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel *Shouldn't the second line be `int *ptr = arr;`?*  Actually, no.  `int (*ptr)[4]` creates `ptr` as a pointer to a full array of four `int` values.    Pointer syntax like that is necessary to dynamically allocate true-multidimensional arrays.  The "2-dimensional arrays" created with nested `malloc()` loops and wrongly described as multidimensional arrays are really 1-d arrays of pointers to multiple 1-d arrays.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> OP: `ptr[0]` points to the first element in the array.

Type confusion.   `ptr[0]` is an array.

`ptr`  is a [pointer to array 4 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*pter%29%5B4%5D).
 `ptr[0]`, like `*ptr` deferences the *pointer to an array*.
`sizeof(ptr[0])` is the size of an array.

---

With `sizeof(ptr[0])`, `ptr[0]` does not incur "an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object"  conversion. (c11dr  §6.3.2.1 3).  With `sizeof`, `ptr[0]` is an array.

Comment: I thought that because `ptr[0]` points to an integer so `sizeof[ptr[0])` equal the size of integer .

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed `ptr[0]` points to an array - in this case, the array `arr[]`.

Comment: No , ptr[0] is the address of first element in the array which means it points to integer . But ptr[0][0] is an integer not points to integer .

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed Agree "But ptr[0][0] is an integer not points to integer ".  "ptr[0] is the address of first element in the array" is not true.

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed yes, the values are same but types are different. ptr[0] has array type and `&ptr[0][0]` has `int *` type

Comment: @chux `ptr[0]` (implicitly converted to `int *`) would evaluate to address of the first int element.

Comment: @GreenTree `sizeof(ptr[0])` does not incur a _implicit conversion_.to `int *`.

Comment: @chux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518255/why-is-array-name-a-pointer-to-the-first-element-of-the-array

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed that reference  about arrays does not apply here. `ptr` is not an array.  It is a pointer, a pointer to an array.

Comment: @chux if you try to print ptr[0] , ptr[0]+1 you will notice that the difference is 4 which means that ptr[0] is pointer to int

Comment: @chux about sizeof - right, I misunderstood the context of what you said

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed That does not.  `printf("someforamt",  ptr[0] , ptr[0]+1)` does something different than `sizeof(ptr[0])`.  The `ptr[0]` in the first case goes through an inplicit conversion.  With `sizeof(ptr[0])`, `ptr[0]` does not.

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed Your reference question's accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18518282/2410359) points out the `sizeof` exception.

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed "**Except** when it is the operand of the **sizeof operator** or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue."  c11 §6.3.2.1 3

Comment: @chux if I want to understand pointers and its related topics very well . What book do you advise me to read ?

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed No book comes to mind.  Best to remember an array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array. [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/2410359) is useful.

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanMohamed cppreference.com and the standard if the first is not enough.

Answer (score 5):

`ptr` here is of type `pointer to an array of 4 int elements` and the array type has size 16 on your platform (sizeof(int) * (number of elemetns)).

> I can't understand why using sizeof(ptr[0]) gives the size of the
>   whole array 16 bytes not the size of only the first element 4 bytes

because C type system has array types. Here both `arr` and `*ptr` has it. What you declare that you have.
To get sizeof int here you should sizeof(ptr[0][0]) - where ptr[0] evaluates to array.

Answer (score 2):

with `int (*ptr)[4] = &arr ;` you have a pointer to an array of four integers and pointing to arr.

`ptr` is now pointing to `arr`, like a double pointer. We can access elements of `arr` using `ptr[0][x]` where `x` could be `0` to `4`.

So `sizeof(ptr[0])` is same as `sizeof(arr)`

Answer (score 2):

By definition, `ptr[0]` is the same as `*(ptr + 0)` which in turn is the same as `*ptr`. Further, `ptr` is initialized with `&arr`, so `*ptr` is `*&arr` and that is just `arr`. Note that the intermediate storage of `&arr` in `ptr` does *not* perform any array decay, so the equivalence is maintained and no type information is lost.

Note that all this is computed at compile-time, just to avoid this additional pitfall.