# Why the code is not giving the expected output here?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, printf, c-strings

This code is for declaring and printing a **string** using **pointer** concept

```
char *strPtr = "HelloWorld";

// temporary pointer to iterate over the string
char *temp = strPtr;
while (*temp != '\0') 
{
    printf("%c", *temp);
    temp++;
}
```

In this code I just want to replace the while loop to for loop.
But when trying the code does not give any output.
My code is as follows

```
char *name = "SAMPLE NAME";
int i;
for (i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    printf("%c", *name);
}
```

This code Does Not work. [Gives blank output]
Where is the error ??

Comment: In the 2nd snippet you should pass `name[i]` to `printf`.

Comment: I would expect it to print "SSSSSSSSSSS".

Comment: @001 you're right.But why it is repeating first characters till its length

Comment: @Theprofessor [why is array name a pointer to the first element of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18518255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for loop

```
for (i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    printf("%c", *name);
}
```

should output the first character of the string pointed to by the pointer `name` as many times as the length of the string  due to this statement

```
    printf("%c", *name);
```

where there is used the same expression `*name` in the call of `printf` that is equivalent to expression `name[0]`.

Also after the loop you should output the new line character `'\n'`.

So the loop should look like

```
for (i = 0; name[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    printf("%c", name[i]);
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

If you want to use a pointer to output the string using for loop then it can look the following way

```
for ( const char *p = name; *p != '\0'; p++)
{
    printf("%c", *p);
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Pay attention to that though in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays nevertheless you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. Thus it is better to declare the pointer `name` with qualifier `const`

```
const char *name = "SAMPLE NAME";
```

Comment: why would it repeat due to `*name`

Comment: @Theprofessor See my updated answer. The pointer name is not being changed within the for loop. So it still points to the first character of the string literal.

Comment: also in using pointer i.e second attempt is it compulsory to declare a new `const char *p`variable.Can't i iterate using same variable `name`

Comment: @Theprofessor In that case you will  lose the pointer to the string literal.  So if you will need it one more you can not determine the address of the string literal.