# Working with C Arrays, Passing to execv()

Tags: c, parameters, execv

I have a function:

```
int exploreDIR (char stringDIR[], char arguments[6][100])
{    
     /*stuff...*/
     execv(filePath, arguments); 
}
```

However, I get the `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘execv’ from incompatible pointer type`

If execv expects `char* const argv[]` for its second argument, why do I receive this warning?

Since arrays are essentially the same thing as pointers to the start of the array, what is the critical difference here between `char arguments[][]` and `char* const argv[]`?

Comment: No wrong in `execv(filePath, arguments); `, `arguments` should be NULL terminated but `arguments[6][100]` can't be NULL terminated as `arguments[i]` is a valid address != NULL

Comment: I'm confused, what is the solution here? I thought that by making arguments of size 6 (of which I only ever planned to fill 5 of them) that the last value would be a NULL pointer and thus cause the  termination. Is this wrong?

Comment: Read: [Difference between `char* str[]` and `char str[][]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-array-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers/17661444#17661444)

Comment: even if you fill only first five argument (from `argument[0]....argument[4]` ) even then  `argument[5]` is not equals to NULL it would be a valid address with strlen = 0, read the answer I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are are passing a pointer (`*`) looking like this:

```
*
`-> aaaa...aaaabbbb...bbbbcccc...cccc
```

It points to memory containing several `char[100]` arrays.

The function expects an argument looking like this:

```
*
`->***
   ||`-> cccc...cccc
   |`-> bbbb...bbbb
   `-> aaaa...aaaa
```

It wants a pointer pointing to memory containing several `char*`.

The two types are different and cannot be automatically converted.

Answer (score 1):

`char arguments[6][100]` is a 600-byte chunk of memory arranged into 6 100-byte segments, whereas `char* argv[]` is an array of pointers to segments of memory which could be anywhere.  One way to see the difference: `arguments[i+1] - arguments[i]` will be 100, while `argv[i+1] - argv[i]` could be ANYTHING.