# Count multi-dimensional array's first dimension

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Right now I can count the first dimension using `var_num=sizeof(var)/sizeof(var[0]);` which by the way I haved researched and am using on my code, but the problem is I don't know how it works, on my output it shows `20 / 4 = 5` and I can't figure out where did that 20 and 4 came from, and I just want to ask how do these values been fetched by `sizeof(var)` and `sizeof(var[0])`, what does that zero mean and is it refering to the 1st or 2nd dimension?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main(){
char *var[][2]={
        {"var0-0","var0-1"},
        {"var1-0","var1-1"},
        {"var2-0","var2-1"},
        {"var3-0","var3-1"},
        {"var4-0","var4-1"},
        };
int var_num=sizeof(var)/sizeof(var[0]);
clrscr();
printf("%d / %d = %d",sizeof(var),sizeof(var[0]),var_num);
getch();
}
```

Comment: These values are hard to believe. I get `40 / 8 = 5` on a 32 bit machine. 40 is the total size, 8 is the size of one entry (which is a `char * [2]`, so I have 5 elements in my 1st dimension. If you do the same on a single row, you get `8 / 4 = 2` because one row consists of 2 entries with 4 bytes each.

Comment: On a 64 bit machine, the results are `80 / 16 = 5` resp. `16 / 8 = 2`.

Comment: Maybe your output comes from a former version of your program which had one dimesion less in the array.

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you get? On my system I get `40 / 8 = 5` (in 32-bit mode) or `80 / 16 = 5` (in 64-bit mode).

Comment: Read [Difference between `char* str[]` and char `str[][]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17661444/1673391)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a complicated example for fun. Say we've

```
char a[10][20][30] = { };
```

Size of `a` will be `sizeof(char) * 10 * 20 * 30`; so `sizeof(a)` = 6000 ([as per C99 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2215454/183120)). `a` can be seen as an array of (10) array of (20) array of (30) characters. Now

- `a[0]` will be one dimension lesser giving us an array of (20) array of (30) characters
- `a[0][0]` will give us an array of (30) characters
- `a[0][0][0]` is a character.

In all these examples `0` is nothing but the first element of the respective array level.

Now finding the length of an array by doing `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` is a trick rooted in the above logic. `sizeof(a[0])` is nothing but the size of an array of 20 array of 30 characters, which is 600. `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` = 6000/600 = 10, giving back the length of the first dimension. Similar math can be done for higher dimensions too.

Since in your question, you've a pointer type `char*` the `sizeof(char*)` should be taken as the base factor which would be multiplied with the lengths of each dimension. Size of a pointer type depends on the machine/architecture type and the compiler you use.

---

Each of us will have different machines and different compilers running on them, so we need a common reference for explanation. Running your program in an [online compiler gives the result](http://ideone.com/d1voTJ) `40 / 8 = 5`. like I've stated above, depending on the platform and compiler, the size of a pointer type will vary.

Like you've written in the comment, your array is of type `char* [5][2]`. Deferencing with `[0]` will remove one level and we've `char* [2]`; thus `sizeof(var[0]) = sizeof(char* [2])` = 8, say that size of two char pointers is 8, which implies that `sizeof(char*)` is 4 on that online machine. On this basis `sizeof(var)` = 4 * 5 * 2 = 40, which is what we see in the output, thereby rightly giving the first array length as 5.

Now your output, like [mentioned by glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567056/count-multiple-dimension-arrays-first-dimension-in-c/19567389?noredirect=1#comment29037487_19567056), is a bit different (perhaps your machine or the compiler's data model is 16-bit); the machine you're running it on in combination with your compiler seems to give *2* as the size of a char pointer i.e `sizeof(char*) = 2`. Now when you do `var[0]`, we've `char* [2]`; its size equals `sizeof(char*) * 2` = 2 * 2 = 4. Likewise `sizeof(var)` = 2 * 5 * 2 = 20. Thus you've `20 / 4 = 5` as output.

> How could I know how many bits do I have per element of the 1st dimension, I mean through calculation?

In `char* [5][2]` each element of the first dimension is the type `char* [2]`, thus it's size is `2 * sizeof(char*)`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I taking hard time to understand it sorry, can you please explain further, on my case that I only have 2 dimension and that my 1st dimension is 5, the second is 2, also you have multipliad 20 by 30 I understand that, but if I only got my var[0] there's no where to multiply it where does that 4 came from?

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify your particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `20` is the size of your array in bytes and the `4` is the size of a single element of your array again in bytes. An array has all its elements of the same type and thus of the same size and so you get its length by dividing its size by the size of a single element. You don't have to use the 0-th element you can use just any other one as well(if you are sure there is an element with such index).

Answer (score 2):

`var[0]` is of type `char **`, it is therefore a pointer. On 32 bits systems, an address takes 4 bytes, so a pointer's size is 4.

`sizeof(var)` equals 20 because you have 5 elements in your array of type `char **`.

Comment: `var[0]` is an array of two `char*`s. Its size should be 8 or 16.

Answer (score 1):

"what does that zero mean?"

`sizeof(var[0])` is asking for the size of an element in the first dimension. The zero is arbitrary but conventional. All of the elements have the same size. Element 0 is `{"var0-0","var0-1"}`, an array of two pointers. Its size is likely to be 8 on a 32-bit system, or 16 on a 64-bit system. Element 1 would be `{"var1-0","var1-1"}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers helped so much, I came to a conclusion that the single element of my 1st dimension could be read differently depending on the bit system that I use in where the bits could be larger or smaller but the values will remain proportion and I will still get the same value.

Comment: But I have a question, How could I know how many bits do I have per element of the 1st dimension, I mean through calculation?