# array pointer (declare and defined in same line gives garbage value while in different line works perfectly fine)

Tags: c, pointers

I am using turbo c
when I declare and define the pointer k diffrently it gives the warning "nonportable pointer conversion " and the outcome for *k shows as garbage

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int i,j,*k;//declaration
int a[3][5] = {
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
{6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
}; *k = &a ; //defination
clrscr();
printf("%d\n",*k);//garbage value
printf("%d\n",*(k+2));//garbage value
printf("%d\n",*(k+3)+1);//garbage value
printf("%d\n",*(k+5)+1);//garbage value
printf("%d\n",++*k);//garbage value
getch();
}
```

where as when define and declare pointer k in same line it gives the result

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int i,j;
int a[3][5] = {
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
{ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
}, *k = &a ;
clrscr();
printf("%d\n",*k);         //1
printf("%d\n",*(k+2));     //3
printf("%d\n",*(k+3)+1);   //5
printf("%d\n",*(k+5)+1);   //7
printf("%d\n",++*k);       //2
getch();
}
```

this problem is taken from "letusC".

**Your response will be greatly appreciated!!**

Answer (score 2):

In first code, after declaration:

```
*k = &a ; //defination
```

Causes undefined behavior because `k` is uninitialized, pointing to a garbage location.

You should correct it as `k = *a;`

Whereas in second code you assign address at the time of declaration.

First, the type of `&a` is `int(*)[3][5]` and type of `a` is `int(*)[5]`. Type of `*a` is `int[5]` that can easily decays int `int*`

Second, the type of `k`is `int*` (and `*k` type is `int`) For expression `*k = &a` you may getting warning in both codes.

To assign address of first element in 2-D array; check following:

First-Code:

```
int *k;
int a[3][5] = {..........}; 
k = *a;
```

Check working code @[codepade](http://codepad.org/7N7CmGnI)

Second-Code:

```
int a[3][5] = {.........}, *k = *a;
```

Check working code @[codepade](http://codepad.org/nQDuXiLx)

To understand it read:

[What does `sizeof(&array)` return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499) and
[What does the 'array name' mean in case of array of char pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17661444/1673391)

Comment: Thanks Grijesh, for ur precious help int making my concept 
But even after i make
    k=a;
code give error"can not convert int[3][5] to int *"

Comment: @anki suggestion `k =a`  was wrong, my mistake, check updated answes with links of working codes.

Comment: Thanks @Grijesh
now i understands** thanks for ur help**
hope u will keep answering to the problems(for others too).

Comment: @anki Yes I will answer (if I will be able to answer)...My suggestion is for you don't read LetUs-C It is outdated a dos based book.

Comment: @anki Pick a book from this link: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

`int *k = &a;` is the same as `int *k; k = &a;`, not `int *k; *k = &a;`.