# Address of elements in an array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[3][4]={2,5,3,2,6,9,0,1,8,10,11,12};
   printf("%u, %u, %u",a,a+1,&a+1);
   return 0;
   getch();
}
```

The output for this code was:

```
 2293472,  2293488, 2293520
```

Can someone explain me how did I get this?

Comment: Nothing surprising about that. What did you expect?

Comment: You're printing the address of a.  Also the getch is not going to do anything since you return before executing getch.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, use `%p` for your format specifier and update your question if so inclined. The very presentation of the results may surprise you. (unrelated, that `getch()` seems somewhat pointless).

Comment: Read  second diagram in this answer [Difference between `char* str[]` and `char str[][]` and how both are stored in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-array-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers/17661444#17661444) I explained for char array.

Comment: Use `%p` to print address.

Comment: As always: _the only right way to reliably print the address of an array or pointer is by casting using the `%p` placeholder, and by casting the corresponding argument to `void *`_ As in `const char *str = "some string"; printf("%p\n", (void *) str);` the end

Answer (score 7):

Here's what's happening with each of `a`, `a+1` and `&a+1`:

- `a`: Since `a` is an array, using `a` causes it to decay into a pointer to the first element of this array, which is an array  of 4 integers (the type of `a` is, therefore, `int (*)[4]`). This is the address you're printing: the address of the first element of the array `a` (which is also the address of the first element in the second-level array)
- `a+1`: This is the same as picking `a` and moving it to the next object, which is `sizeof(int)*4` bytes away, because each element of `a` is an array of 4 integers. Thus, this prints the address of the second element in `a`.
- `&a+1`: This is one of the few exceptions where the array-to-pointer decayment rule is not appplied. Arrays do not decay into pointers when they are the operand of the reference operator (`&`), the operand of `sizeof`, or a string literal initializer. Thus, `&a` is not a pointer to pointer to array of 4 integers, rather than that, it's the address of your array, which, by convention, is the address of the first element in `a`. The address is the same as `a` (yes, `a` and `&a` have the same address), but the difference is that `&a` has type pointer to array[3][4] of int, that is, `int (*)[3][4]`, meaning that the next object (the result of `&a+1`) is `sizeof(int)*3*4` bytes away, and that's the address you get.

Side note: you should use `%p` to print pointer values instead of relying on the fact that pointers are the same size as an unsigned int. This is correct:

```
printf("%p, %p, %p", (void *) a, (void *) (a+1), (void *) (&a+1));
```

Looking at the output you got, I can see that `sizeof(int)` is 4 in your system. With a little maths, you can see that indeed `a+1` is `a`+16 (2293472 + 4*4 = 2293488), and `&a+1` is 4*3*4 bytes away; 2293472 + 4*3*4 = 2293520

Comment: Type of `a` is `int[3][4]` that decays into `int(*)[4]`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That's what I said.

Answer (score 2):

Printing an address using `%u` is undefined behavior, so the program is free to print *anything*. In this case, the behavior has obviously been implemented by the specific compiler, this is what it does:

- `a` is the array itself, so it prints the address where the 2D array is allocated. Apparently address 2293472d.
- `a+1` means that since `a` is part of an arithmetic expression, it will decay into a pointer to its first element, which is in turn an array of 4 elements. "array + 1" means that you which to take the address of this array + the size of such an array. In bytes, it means that you want the address of the array + `4*sizeof(int)`. In other words, 2293472d + 4*4 = 223488d.
- `&a+1` means that you get an array pointer to the whole array, then increase that by the sizeof of one whole array. 2293472d + `3*4*sizeof(int)` = 2293520.

The key to understanding this is to know the difference between *arrays*, *pointers* and *array pointers*, which are 3 different, yet closely related types. The [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) explains this better than I can. The linked-to chapter is mandatory reading for all C programmers, beginners and veterans all alike.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is going on...

you are printing just `a` and that's a pointer and obviously would give the address value of that on your output screen.

Next you are printing out `a+1`. The size of int data type is 4 bytes. The address of a[0][0] here is `2293472`.Now you are asking for the address value of a+1 where a consists of 4 integers. this takes up 4*4=16 bytes of memory. so a+1 produces value of a added to 16. that is `2293488`.

Next you print out &a+1. that gives the address that is completely after the area allocated to the variable(i.e. integer array here). your array consists 12 values that implies it takes 48 bytes of size. So the output you get is 2293472+48=`2293520`