# search a file with strcmp (run time error)

Tags: c, strcmp

I have problem with my code , I get run time error.

This code is suppose to ask the user to enter  a name and then go through the 
file and search for the input entered by the user.

and I got this warning.

> ( [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

```
void search()
{
 FILE *infile;
int i=0,found=0;
char list[SIZE], str[SIZE];

infile = fopen("records.txt","r");
printf("enter a book name to search in the list > /n");
gets(list);
i=0; 
while (!found && i<SIZE) {
        if(strcmp(list[i], str) == 0)
            found = 1;
        else
          i++;
}

if(found)
        printf("%s is in the list at row %d\n",str,i);
    else printf("%s is not in the list.\n", str);

  printf("\n");    
}
```

Comment: `list` should be either  [`char* list[]` or `char list[][] `](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564608/what-does-the-array-name-mean-in-case-of-array-of-char-pointers/17661444#17661444)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with the usage of [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). As per the man page,

> `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);`

it expects a `const char *` as both of the arguments. But  you're passing `list[i]`, which is a `char`.

Also, never use `gets()`. It's very unsafe, use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

That said, i think your program is seriously broken.

1. you opened the file, never read anything from it. Why?
2. the `str` is used uninitialized. Lead to Undefined behavior.
3. You never closed the file.

Comment: good answer, but OP also don't know how to read file, declaration of list is also incorrect.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You're very right sir, but that is not the scope of this question, IMHO. That is why, I added last three bullets. I addressed the question present in the title. :-)